# Premier Signal Processing conference

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications

I am interested in the following area:

- Digital Communications and Signal Processing, especially used for VLSI design of communication systems.
  (Some sub-topics may be MIMO communications, channel estimation, coding, symbol timing/carrier recovery algorithms etc...)

I would like know the leading journals and conferences are for this field (most respected conference or with impact to industry).  For example, for chip design it would be JSSC (journal) and ISSCC (conference).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[IEEE ICASSP](https://2022.ieeeicassp.org/) is probably still the largest international conference on communications and signal processing. IEEE Transactions on [Signal Processing](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/mostRecentIssue.jsp?punumber=7) and [Communications](https://www.comsoc.org/publications/journals/ieee-tcom) are well-regarded journals.